# guardar un valor con datos extra laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

tengo un input en mi vista asi:

```
<input type="text" name="texto>
```

que guardo en mi controlador

```
public function TextoStore(Request $request) {
$validatedData = $request->validate([ texto' => 'required|max:255' ]);
$Texto = Textos::create($validatedData);
```

y mi modelo se ve asi

```
protected $primaryKey = 'idTextos';
protected $fillable = ['texto',];
```

me gustaría guardar el valor que inserto como texto con un valor adicionar, es decir si en el campo se manda el texto "hola" inserte en mi base de datos "Thola" con la letra T unida al hola.

Comment: Tienes algunos errores con el uso de comillas, ¿fue solo al momento de copiar el código?

Comment: en realidad es un ejemplo, estoy trabajando un calendario clasico de botstrap y al poner la fecha es opcional poner la hora de inicio y hora de concluir. es facil colocar la fecha en un input de tipo Date pero la hora tiene que ser T12:00 por ejemplo , puedo guardar la hora pero es obligatorio que si el valor hora existe inicie con T

Comment: Y dónde está el código donde guardas la información en la DB? Ahí es solo cuestión de concatenar el input que viene por request con el string "T".

Comment: el codigo esta en el modelo se ve como $filllable que en laravel hace el insert incluido el token csrf y csrf_field que se designa en el tema de formularios. como es la configuración base no lo puse ya que esa parte ni se toca :S pero el insert esta en el Textos::create y $fillable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que pones en la pregunta, podés concatenarlos con el [operador de concatenación ('.')](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) , después de validar y antes de insertar el nuevo registro en la base de datos

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([ 'texto' => 'required|max:255' ]);

$texto_agregado_previo = 'esta parte se agregó en el controlador. El texto original era: ';
$texto_agregado_al_final = '  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯';

// en esta línea puedes sobreescribir el valor que llegó en el request 
// mira como los . concatenan los strings
$validatedData['texto'] = $texto_agregado_previo . $validatedData['texto'] . $texto_agregado_al_final;

$Texto = Texto::create($validatedData);
```

Comment: muchas gracias :) quedo bien